# migrate configuration from dispatcher servlet xml to java class. Do i need both(java class and xml)?

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

Following is the code for my dispatcher-servlet.xml and configuration class :

Where do i put my db configuration and entity definitions?

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        // Default view
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter basicMetricFilter() {
        return new PieRequestMetricsFilter();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* put those configurations in `MvcConfig` but **it's NOT a good idea**. A better approach is to define **one config for each architectural aspect** of your application and then put related configs only in each one. Suppose you have a web application with traditional layered architecture. In this example you would have `WebConfig` just like your `MvcConfig` class, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.example.web")
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        // Default view
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
    }

    @Bean
    public Filter basicMetricFilter() {
        return new PieRequestMetricsFilter();
    }
}
```

Also, you could have a `RepositoryConfig` that contains your data access related configurations, like this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackges = "com.example.repository")
public class RepositoryConfig() {
    // put your datasource, entity manager, jdbc templates, tx managers here
}
```

For wiring these configurations together, there is no need for any xml file such as dispatcher servlet or web.xml. You can define a `WepApplicationInitializer` that defines parent and child configs in this scenario, like this:

```
public class MyWebAppInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { RepositoryConfig.class, SecurityConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class[] { WebConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] { "/" };
    }

}
```

`WebApplicationInitializer` is an interface provided by Spring MVC that ensures your implementation is detected and automatically used to initialize any Servlet 3 container. An abstract base class implementation of `WebApplicationInitializer` named `AbstractDispatcherServletInitializer` makes it even easier to register the `DispatcherServlet` by simply overriding methods to specify the servlet mapping and the location of the `DispatcherServlet` configuration.
For more details please consult the spring documentation.

Comment: thanks Ali, that answered my question perfectly. :) 

few resources that i found helpful : http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.0.RC1/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.html

http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hibernate-annotation-example/

http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-mvc-4-angularjs-example/

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-static-resources
 :)

Comment: Your welcome. Usually spring projects have nice and very useful documentations.

Comment: Yes. Docs for both spring and angular(just started) are awesome.

one more issue that i am getting is that i can't find static resources : 

@Override
 public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry){
  registry.addResourceHandler("/static/**").addResourceLocations("/static/");
 }

Comment: this is what i defined in my config class. and i used the following in my jsp:
<link href="<c:url value='/static/css/table.css'/>" rel="stylesheet"></link>

can you help?

Comment: where is `/static/` directory located compared to your classpath? maybe changing it to `...addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")` fixes the problem.

Comment: webapp/static/
i did that and it is giving me : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.home_jsp now :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205069/servletexception-in-left-do-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp

Comment: seems there might be something wrong with the way i am using the c tag from jstl..... the link doesn't resolve my issue completely.....thanks for help though.

Comment: stupid me. i had put space between <c: url... 
fixed. :)